# Getting "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict." when trying to add rows into azure table

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I am trying to upload azure table row using PowerShell and I am receiving the below error. Could this be due to wrong Azure Storage powershell modules? I am using Azure.Storage 4.0.2 module.

Below is the Code:

```
# Getting all the resource group
$resource_group_list = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup

# Iterating through the resource group
foreach($resource_group_list_iterator in $resource_group_list){

    # Since the solution applies for virtual machines,
    # obtain the list of virtual machines for the resource group
    $virtual_machine_list = get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $resource_group_list_iterator.ResourceGroupName

    # Proceed only when resource group contains virtual machines
    if(!($virtual_machine_list -eq $null)){

        # Iterate through the virtual machine list
        foreach($virtual_machine_list_iterator in $virtual_machine_list){

            # Creat an unique ID by concatinating 'Resource Group name' and 'Virtual Machine name'
            $unique_id = $resource_group_list_iterator.ResourceGroupName + "__" + $virtual_machine_list_iterator.name
            Write-Host $unique_id

            # Obtain the tags associated with the virtual machines
            $virtual_machine_tags = (get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $resource_group_list_iterator.ResourceGroupName -Name $virtual_machine_list_iterator.name).Tags

            # Iterate over the tags to match the tag that we are looking for
            foreach($tag_iterator in $virtual_machine_tags){
    if($tag_iterator.keys -eq 'owner' -and $tag_iterator.values -eq 'ibm'){

        # Store the tags in a variable to later store it in Azure table
        $virtual_machine_tag = $tag_iterator.keys.ToString()
        $virtual_machine_value = $tag_iterator.Values.ToString()


        $partitionKey1 = $unique_id
        if($virtual_machine_tag -eq $null) {$virtual_machine_tag = $null}
        if($virtual_machine_value -eq $null) {$virtual_machine_value = $null}

    $hash = @{}
    $hash.Add('uniqueid',$unique_id)
    $hash.Add('key',$virtual_machine_tag)
    $hash.add('value',$virtual_machine_value)

    Add-StorageTableRow `
    -table $azure_table_object `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey1 `
    -rowKey ("CA") `
     -property $hash

        #Write-Output "Key: " $tag_iterator.keys
        #Write-Output "Value: " $tag_iterator.Values
    }
}


            #Write-Host "Tags: " $virtual_machine_tags
            #Write-Host " "
        }


    }


}
```

Below is the exception that I received:

```
Exception calling "Execute" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an 
error: (409) Conflict."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRmStorageTable\1.0.0.21\AzureRmS
torageTableCoreHelper.psm1:267 char:16
+ ...      return ($table.CloudTable.Execute((invoke-expression "[Microsoft ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException
```

I have gone thru few online resources on how to troubleshoot, but I did not get any solution.

Comment: 409 is typically returned if you try to add a row with the same partition and row key as an existing row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As junnas mentioned that 409 error means that add a row with same partition key and row key as existing row.

You could print the [partition Key and row key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#tables-entities-and-properties) before insert into the table.If want to get the unique_id  we could use the Guid, please have a try to use  `$unique_id = $resource_group_list_iterator.ResourceGroupName + "__" + $virtual_machine_list_iterator.name+[guid]::newguid()`

**Note:** In your case, I suggest that you could use the vaule **CA** as partion key and **$unique_id** as rowkey.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. The code works perfectly fine now. However, the "key" and "value" is inserted as: ""System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.String"". Do you know why? And if I remove the "tostring()" method, I am getting an exception --> Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "2".
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRmStorageTable\1.0.0.21\AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1:260 char:4